# Disable WS-I magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, soap-api-v2, wsi

Can WS-I be disabled for Magento 2 (v2.1.6). It's blocking an API connection to a third party shipping portal (Royal Mail Click and Drop).

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Might be this article will help you:   https://alanstorm.com/magentos_wsi_compliant_api/

Comment: Nope, references magento 1 versions only.